# horizontal accordion tutorial css issue i think

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been following this tutorial on how to make a horizontal accordion [tutorial here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8pi6MFXrN4)
I've gone through the code and pretty much have exactly what he has. My problem I think is my css, when you click a tab the last panel animates but the next panel drops down and doesn't animate can someone show me whats wrong either its my css or something in jquery could you give me some help with this please here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4YXX/4/) . I dont know exactly what is the issue but I floated all my elements to the left.

P.S the 'visible' variable is the current content panel
html:

```
 <div class="accordion" data-style="horizontal">        
    <h3 class="header" id="tab1"></h3>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <h3 class="header" id="tab2"></h3>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <h3 class="header" id="tab3"></h3>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <h3 class="header" id="tab4"></h3>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.accordion {
    width:460px; height:300px
}
.accordion .header {
    width:40px; height:100%
}
.accordion .content{
      background:#dedede; height:100%
}
.accordion .header, accordion .content {
     float:left; height:100%; clear:none
}
#tab1 {
     background:#C90 
}
#tab2 {
     background:#C60
}    
#tab3 {
     background:#C30
}
#tab4 {
     background:#C00
}
```

jQuery:

```
function accordion(rate) {
    var tab = $('.accordion').find('h3'),        
        visible = tab.next().filter(':last'),
        width = visible.outerWidth();

    tab.next().filter(':not(:last)').css({'display':'none', 'width':0});

    tab.click(function() {
        if(visible.prev()[0] == this) {
             return;   
        }
        visible.animate({width: 0}, {duration:rate});
        visible = $(this).next().animate({'width':width}, {duration:rate});
    });
}

accordion(350);
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work at all.

Comment: Here's one that runs: http://jsfiddle.net/L4YXX/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to make this a comment.

Have you compared your code to the source code linked in the comment of the tutorial video?

http://codecompendium.com/archives/downloads/

There are some significant differences. The Jquery you have in your original post is different to your jsFiddle.

Your Jquery should look more like :

```
function accordion(rate) {
var tab = $('.accordion').find('.header'),        
    visible = tab.next().filter(':last'),
    width = visible.outerWidth();

tab.next().filter(':not(:last)').css({'display':'none', 'width':0});

tab.click(function() {
    if(visible.prev()[0] == this) {
         return;   
    }
    visible.animate({width:0}, {duration:rate});
    visible = $(this).next().animate({width:width}, {duration:rate});
});
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    accordion(350);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the code. I couldn't find it. I have downloaded it now I can get to work and figure it out. Cheers man